# Unity 3d controlling object visibility

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two game objects namely `objA` and `objB` where the later is a child of former. `ObjA` is active and `B` is disabled. I wanted `objB` to appear when pointer enters and to disappear when pointer exits. I want this not just once but forever. 
I have tried following code attached with `objA` to control visibility of `objB` but it's unsuccessful. Could someone help me plz:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class eventvisbtoggle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PointerEnter(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        ObjB.gameobject.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void PointerExit(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        ObjB.gameobject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I answered your first question and provided you a link to learn Unity and C#. I don't think you took that advice. Good luck!

Comment: @Programmer: thank you so much for your advice. I think my requirement is very basic and towards learning a very first stage of showing/hiding and object nothing else. I beleieve there are experts here who will guide me to learn other than the unity3d tutorials which are unfriendly for a novice user like me.

Comment: "learning a very first stage of showing/hiding"  This, I showed you how do with `SetActive` which you have not accepted as answer yet. There are no experts here that will guide you learn Unity. stackoverflow is not a tutorial website. It is to solve problems and you should help yourself by learning the basics first. If Unity Tutorials are hard for you, try tutorials from **Brackeys** on youtube. Follow one tutorial and finish it, then you will understand how to declare ObjA and ObjB as GameObject and how to implement interface. https://www.youtube.com/user/Brackeys

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the enabled state of a GameObject and whether or not its is visible.  active determines whether or not scripts and other components attached to the object function.  A component called the Renderer is what actually draws the GameObject in the scene.  What you want to do is disable the Renderers that are attached to the object

```
foreach(var r in GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>()){
    r.enabled = false;
}
```

Note that this is very slow code, you should assign the appropriate renderers to your script using the editor, but this is just an example.